# Is what I said shirk

Tags: allah, sin, shirk, doubts

I accidentally said I only worship Jesus as a prophet I said this unintentionally is this shirk? Please help and I’m asking Allah for forgiveness and I’m crying but I’m not sure if I feel the heart burning and I feel like i will never make it to Jannah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relax. Allah will not hold us accountable for our unintentional/ignorant mishaps. It was a simple mistake and if you don't actually believe what you said then you're fine.